# Cannot format or change disk properties

Tags: partitioning, ssd, formatting

I have a KingDian SSD that had Windows 10 installed and suddenly this disk has stopped booting. I have tried formating the partition and also changing the partition table from `DOS` to `GPT`, but although both `fdisk` and `gparted` says the operations were successfully accomplished after I close `fdisk` or `gparted` the disk remains the same.

- Disk before operation:
  [image: disk before operation]
- Operation message:
  [image: Operation message]
- Disk after operation (same as before):
  [image]

Is there a way I can force format this disk? Is there any trick that could save this SSD? Now it is completely useless as it is.

note: I have tried doing the same tasks on other computers and other OS (arch, manjaro and windows)

**Edit 1**:

I ran the [three steps](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive/Memory_cell_clearing#Step_1_-_Make_sure_the_drive_security_is_not_frozen) for starting ATA Secure Erase and checked if my disk was like the one in the example. My output:

```
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
        enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    Security level high
    2min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 2min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Checksum: correct
```

I then ran security-erase as step 3 says:

`hdparm --user-master u --security-erase PasSWorD /dev/sda`

```
/dev/sda:
 Issuing SECURITY_ERASE command, password="PasSWorD", user=user
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

**Edit 2**:
Running: `smartctl -H /dev/sda`

Outputs:

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
No failed Attributes found.
```

Comment: Does the disk report anything unusual via SMART? Can you try running `blkdiscard` on the device, or starting ATA Secure Erase?

Comment: @grawity I get "blkdiscard: /dev/sdb: BLKDISCARD ioctl failed: Operation not supported" when running `blkdiscard /dev/sdb`

Comment: Is the disk attached directly to SATA, or through a USB adapter?

Comment: @grawity it is connected through USB. SMART short test outputs `SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED`

Comment: @grawity should I try doing these steps using SATA?

Comment: Yes, it'll rule out a bad USB adapter and it'll allow blkdiscard (SSD TRIM) to work as well.

Comment: I have connected the SSD through SATA. Now `blkdiscard` doesn't output anything. I have also hot-replugged the SATA cable to make it not frozen, but this doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Comment: @grawity kindly see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem was **my disk was failing**. This is the second time I face problems when formatting a disk and then find out it is failing.

In most cases, you can still recover data from a failing disk, but it is not recommended to insist on using it for everyday needs.

The solution for me was to, unfortunately, buy a new disk to use.